# IHeaderResponse cannot be resolved after migration to 1.6

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to migrate a site from Wicket 1.5.8 to 1.6.20. The build fails, showing the error description:

> The type org.apache.wicket.markup.html.IHeaderResponse cannot be
>   resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
OKCancelWindow.java /LatinParserK/src/main/java/com/<site>/access   line 1  Java Problem
```

The file OKCancelWindow.java shows the error on the first line

```
package com.<site>.access;
```

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for org.apache.wicket.markup.html.IHeaderResponse.
>   Fix the build path then try building this project

```
LatinParserK        Unknown Java Problem
```

I am not sure whether the specified file or the specified library is the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This class has been moved to package `org.apache.wicket.markup.head`. Make sure your Wicket libraries are also upgraded to 6.x.

Comment: The code is defined by:import org.apache.wicket.markup.head.IHeaderResponse;
The error is different. I thought that all of the libraries came in jar files. I do not know how to re-compile libraries. Can you provide instructions? I am using Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Your libraries should have version for Wicket 6.x. If they are not upgraded already then you will need to upgrade them yourself.

Comment: I have folder C:\Users\joe\.m2\repository\org\apache\wicket\wicket-util\6.20.0 with files in it, similar to v1.5.8. I also see an error in the log: IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /wicket-util:6.21.0.pom [effective] _and also_ !MESSAGE Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:

Comment: It is hard to help you without the stacktraces. It seems your Maven setup is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I archived the code and started from a fresh build. There were still problems, which were resolved after I found this code in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

The specified library (1.5.6) was not compatible with version 6.20.0 code. A change to

```
<version>${wicket.version}</version>
```

corrected the problem. Changes to incompatible code was easy to implement.